# Passing variables by reference

Tags: c#, reference

If I have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    Boo a;
    public Foo (ref Boo  b)
    {
        a=b;
    }
}
```

Is `a` going to be a reference to `b`, or a is going to copy the value which ref `b` points to ?
If it copies the value, how can I make that `a` reference to `b` and `b` reference to the argument reference?(Like Java does)

Comment: Take a look at http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html.

Comment: In that particular example, the `ref` modifier does in fact nothing, as you're not assigning anything back to `b`. Copying the reference is always done and both the variable and parameter end up pointing at the very same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `a` going to be a reference to `b`, or `a` is going to copy the value which `ref b` points to ?

It depends:

if `Boo` is a reference type, such as below, `a` will point to the same instance after the call

```
public class Boo
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

If `Boo` is a value type, such as below, `a` will be a memberwise copy of what `ref b` was pointing at.

```
public struct Boo
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following example:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public Foo MyFoo { get; set; }

        public Bar(Foo paramFoo)
        {
            this.MyFoo = paramFoo;
        }
    }
```

And this sequence:

```
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.Name = "First Foo";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f.Name);

        Bar b = new Bar(f);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(b.MyFoo.Name);

        b.MyFoo.Name = "Renaming Bar Name";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f.Name);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(b.MyFoo.Name);
```

The output will be:

```
First Foo
First Foo
Renaming Bar Name
Renaming Bar Name
```

In this case, we're passing `f` reference to `Bar` ctor, so `f` and `MyFoo` both point to the same memory address, **but they are different variables**. This means that, if we do the following

```
        b.MyFoo = new Foo();
        b.MyFoo.Name = "Yet another foo";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(f.Name);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(b.MyFoo.Name);
```

The output will be

```
Renaming Bar Name
Yet another foo
```

To change this behavior, you should use the `ref` keyword, so you're sending the pointer to that variable.

Comment: I didn't downvote in this case, but I suspect the downvote is because there are a couple issues with your answer. (a) "well known value types" is misleading - you can create your own value type and it will be passed by value.  (b) using `ref` doesn't make value types behave like reference types; it simply passes the value of the argument by reference.  Passing a reference type by reference is different than passing a reference type by value.

Comment: @MichaelPetito If you visit the link I provided, you'll see that enums and structs are the first items, which resolves the "you can create your own value type" part. Using `ref` with a value type will pass it as a reference type. Using `ref` with a reference type has no additional value.

Comment: You are incorrect regarding passing reference types by `ref`.  A variable whose value is a reference type is storing a pointer to the instance of the reference type.  Passing such a value by `ref` passes a pointer to the value, which is a pointer to a pointer.  This allows the method receiving the value by `ref` to change the value of the variable passed to the method.  In the case of a reference type, this allows the method to change the value to point to another instance of the reference type.

Comment: @MichaelPetito you're correct about what a reference type is, but not so about `ref`. Using `ref` with a parameter that would be sent as reference type, such as the OP does, makes no difference.

Comment: No, it does make a difference.  Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/mpetito/af1ad9111e7eeecbd66e .. You're confusing reference / value types with passing by reference / value.  You can pass a reference type by value: you're passing a copy of a pointer value.  You can pass a reference type by reference: you're passing a pointer to a pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a difference in passing reference types normally and using ref keyword.

Following code should explain, please read comments carefully:

```
class Class6
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boo b = new Boo { BooMember = 5 };
        Console.WriteLine(b.BooMember);

        Foo f = new Foo(b);
        // b is unaffected by the method code which is making new object
        Console.WriteLine(b.BooMember);

        Foo g = new Foo(ref b);
        // b started pointing to new memory location (changed in the method code)
        Console.WriteLine(b.BooMember);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    Boo a;
    public Foo(Boo b)
    {
        a = b;

        // b is just a reference, and actually is a copy of reference passed,
        // so making it point to new object, dosn't affect actual object , check in calling code
        b = new Boo();
    }

    public Foo(ref Boo b)
    {
        a = b;

        // b is just a reference, but actual reference itself is copied,
        // so making it point to new object would make the calling code object reference to point 
        // to new object. check in the calling code.
        b = new Boo();
    }
}

public class Boo
{
    public int BooMember { get; set; }
}
```